# rising_edge(clk) not synthesizable

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

I am learning and programming VHDL for Lattice FPGA to mimic the functionality of 74HCT245. Below is my Code.

I keep getting **statement is not synthesizable since it does not hold its value under NOT(clock-edge) condition. VHDL-1242** error,

```
 entity HCT541 is
  port (Clk       : in    std_logic;
        A         : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := "1011101010111010";
        BA        : out   std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        n_OE, DIR : in    std_logic;
        M_D       : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := "0000000000000001";
        D         : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := "1011101010111010";
        BD        : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := "1011101010111010");
end HCT541;

architecture df of HCT541 is
  signal n_OE_1, n_OE_2 : std_logic := '0';
begin

  process(Clk, n_OE, DIR)
  begin

    if ((BD = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ" or D = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ") and n_OE = '0') then
      BD <= "0000000000000000";
      D  <= M_D;
    end if;

    M_D <= M_D + '1';

    CLK1 : if(rising_edge(Clk)) then

      if(n_OE_1 = '0' and n_OE_2 = '0') then
        A  <= A - '1';
        BA <= A;
      else
        BA <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
      end if;

      if (n_OE = '0' and DIR = '1') then
        D  <= M_D;
        BD <= D;
      elsif (n_OE = '0' and DIR = '0') then
        BD <= BD - '1';
        D  <= BD;
      elsif (n_OE = '1') then
        BD <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
        D  <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
      end if;

    end if CLK1;

  end process;

end df;
```

any thoughts ?

Anything wrong with using rising_edge ?

Comment: Guideline:  Always code your tristate logic separate from any flip-flop logic.

Comment: rising_edge(clk) is fine. It's what comes _before_ `if rising_edge(clk)` that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

A few guidelines:

1. Draw a picture of the hardware your want.  Then code the picture.
2. Hardware can only check for 1's and 0's.  So your checks for Z are
   problematic
3. Only drive tristates in combinational processes. Otherwise there are many surprises and mistakes.
4. Many FPGAs do not have internal tristates, and hence, only support them for primary outputs.

Interpreting @ Jonathan Drolet's comment about "mixing combinational process with synchronous process."  Think of this from the output perspective.

Your synchronous processes ideally are of the form:

```
SyncProc : process (Clk) is
begin
  -- do not do logic here
  if rising_edge(Clk) then
   -- do synch stuff.  
   -- logic is ok in here
  end if ; 
  -- do not do logic here
end process SyncProc ;
```

Your combinational processes ideally are of the form:

```
CombProc : process (sig1, sig2, ...) is
begin
  -- do logic stuff here
  -- do not do clocks here
end process CombProc ;
```

Some tools will let you get away with more.

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure since your post's formatting is hard to read. It seems you assigns `BD` inside the rising_edge(clk) statement **and** outside of it, which can't be. `BD` is either a register, or it's not.

Do not mix combinational process with synchronous process. While not technically wrong by VHDL standard, it's prone to mistake like the one you have. Basically, a process sensible on `clk` should not be sensible to any other signal, except an asynchronous reset.

Separate your process into one that is sensible on `n_OE` and `DIR` and a second sensible on `CLK`. It will be clear that you assign `BD` in both processes, which translate to multiple drivers for a signal, which is usually wrong in synthesis.